# How can I use prefetch_related in self related model

Tags: django, django-models, django-orm

I have `Menu` model which has ForeignKey named parent related with itself.

If parent is None it means this menu is parent menu if it shows another Menu object it means it is submenu for its parent(many-to-one relation)

Here is my problem, I want to get all menus with its submenus using `prefetch_related`, How can I do it?

> **Note:** I do not want to get submenus going database each time in for
> menu

Here is my model class

```
class Menu(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    language = models.ForeignKey(Language)
    parent = models.ForeignKey("self", default=None, blank=True,
                               null=True, related_name="submenus")
```

Here is my query

```
pm2 = Menu.objects.filter(parent=None, language__code=language, menutype=menutype)
          .prefetch_related("submenus").order_by("order")
for p in pm2:
    print(p.title)
    print(p.submenus)
```

When I print the submenus the result is `app.Menu.None`

Comment: Your model doesn't mention `submenus` at all, so I would expect `.prefetch_related("submenus")` to give an error. Will your submenus have their own submenus, or will your menus only have two levels? If you have multiple levels, then you may want to look at [django-mptt](https://github.com/django-mptt/django-mptt).

Comment: django-mptt is hopelessly convoluted to work with. I would suggest using materialized paths instead (e.g. https://communities.bmc.com/docs/DOC-9902)

Comment: Was this issue ever resolved?

Comment: @Bigbob556677 It wasn't an issue at all. Please check [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60796965/2549021) to see why.

Comment: queryset = Menu.objects.filter(parent=None, language__code=language, menutype=menutype).order_by("order").prefetch_related('submenus', 'submenus__submenus', 'submenus__submenus__submenus', "submenus__submenus__submenus__submenus")

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use `prefetch_related` since this is used for `many-to-many` relationships, instead, you can use `select_related`.

So your query would be

```
pm2 = Menu.objects.filter(
    parent=None, language__code=language, menutype=menutype
).select_related(
    "submenus"
).order_by(
    "order"
)
```

Comment: Sorey for late response. In here i think i need to use prefetch_related because i want to get submenus and submenus is the reverse ForeignKeys "parent" field.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are working with a tree (by using an Adjacency List), then neither `select_related` nor `prefetch_related` will work correctly if you have more than a single level of parent-child relationships. Instead, you will need something that materialises the tree.

https://pypi.org/project/django-closure-tree/ provides a framework for building Postgres views that will handle this type of construct, and gives you some tools for making querying this simpler.

The actual code behind this is surprisingly simple: https://schinckel.net/2016/01/27/django-trees-via-closure-view/

Answer (score 0):

> When I print the submenus the result is `app.Menu.None`

This is happening because the OP is printing `print(p.submenus)` which is just a `RelatedManager`. It can be verified by checking the type of `p.submenus`:

```
# this is what it prints in django 1.11
>>> type(p.submenus)                                                                                                                                                                                                               
django.db.models.fields.related_descriptors.create_reverse_many_to_one_manager.<locals>.RelatedManager
```

To access a queryset from the m2m relation, the correct way is to use `.all()`:

```
print(p.submenus.all())
```

Comment: did u answer this question? i think you post wrong question

Comment: @Kevin Yes, I have answered the question. I am sorry but I don't follow what you mean by `i think you post wrong question`.

Answer (score 0):

The reason you are seeing `app.Menu.None` is because you are trying to print a related manager object `submenus` directly. You can't print a manager object directly, you need to iterate over it to access the related objects (in this case, the submenus).

```py
pm2 = Menu.objects.filter(parent=None, language__code=language, menutype=menutype).prefetch_related("submenus").order_by("order")
for p in pm2:
    print(p.title)
    for submenu in p.submenus.all():  # Iterate over the related objects
        print(submenu.title)  # Print the title of each submenu
```

In the modified code, `p.submenus.all()` retrieves all the submenus related to a particular menu `p`. The `all()` function is used with a manager to retrieve all objects. Since `submenus` is a related manager (as specified by the `related_name` argument in the `ForeignKey` field), you use `all()` to retrieve all related submenu objects.

The `prefetch_related("submenus")` ensures that Django fetches all related submenus in a single query rather than hitting the database for each individual submenu, improving performance when you have many menus.

Answer (score -1):

For Example u have 4Level self u need code like this :

```
queryset = Menu.objects.filter(parent=None, language__code=language, menutype=menutype).order_by("order").prefetch_related('submenus', 'submenus__submenus', 'submenus__submenus__submenus', "submenus__submenus__submenus__submenus")
```

Comment: That looks like a terrible idea. What if there are 5 levels?